# Android: EditText with arrow at bottom line that points down

Tags: android, android-layout, xamarin, xamarin.android

I need to implement custom styling for one EditText control. It should contain arrow at bottom line. Here is how it should look:

[image: Android: EditText with arrow]

As i am implementing material design, if i focues this EditText, it should change color to accent as well. I can cut arrow as image and put it above line and then on focus change image. Is there better way? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's worth it to take a look at 9-patch images and how you can set them as drawbles for your `EditText`. It'd allow you to have the whole thing in one image and have it grow/scale nicely as you maybe use it in a variety of differently sized `EditTexts`. Once you learn how to create one such image, you can quickly take a look to see how the Android default controls are using them for a background.